# Swift, Parsing XLSX file by CoreXLSX

Tags: swift, excel, xlsx

I'm trying to parse an XLSX file downloaded from http://api.pfs-ltd.org/api/v101/postcode?ownerid=127&key=bc8362af-55ae-4771-be82-e7c83fb6ec9d
Issue is when I download the file on run time and try to parse it, it throws exception "CoreXLSX.CoreXLSXError error 0." on parseWorksheetPaths()

here is my code to parse file

```
guard let file = XLSXFile(filepath: path) else { return }

    let alphaArr = ["A", "B", "C"]
    do {
        let docPath = try file.parseDocumentPaths()
        let workSheet = try file.parseWorksheet(at: docPath.first ?? "")
        let sharedStrings = try file.parseSharedStrings()
        for path in try file.parseWorksheetPaths() {
            let ws = try file.parseWorksheet(at: path)
            for alphabt in alphaArr {
                let cells = ws.cells(atColumns: [ColumnReference(alphabt)!])
                let columnCStrings = cells.compactMap{ $0.value }.compactMap { Int($0) }.compactMap {sharedStrings.items[$0].text }
                print(columnCStrings)
            }
        }
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
```

Comment: So you don't get an error when the file is already downloaded or what do you mean with "on run time"?

Comment: When you remove `localizedDescription` from `print(error.localizedDescription)`, you can see, that you have `CoreXLSXError.archiveEntryNotFound` error. Unfortunately, I don't know what can you do with this.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson for this specific file, when I download it and open it once and hit the command+s and use that file directly in workspace it works perfectly fine. But when I download it and use it directly in workspace without opening it, it throws the same error "CoreXLSX.CoreXLSXError error 0."

Comment: Could it be an asynchronous issue, you are trying to access the file before it is fully downloaded?

Comment: I don't think so @JoakimDanielson 
I accessed the file after it was downloaded.